# Should characters in <pre><code> be html encoded?

Tags: html

Writing documentation in html requires some code examples. What to do with characters that should be replaced with `&amp;` and `&gt;` etc.? Should they be encoded in this case too? When I have these characters inside of `<pre><code>` tags, they display like they should as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should use HTML entities inside of <pre> and <code>.  Some browsers are forgiving, but leaving `<` and `>` as non-entities won't work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't you'll eventually come across code like: print "</code>".   And it won't work non-escaped.